# Writing a class using IHtmlContent and IHtmlHelper

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
namespace Payroll.Web
{
    public static class Extentions
    {
        public static IHtmlContent LabelwithStyleFor<TModel, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
          Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
        {
            return HtmlHelper.LabelFor(expression, new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-form-label" });
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have tried this code but it's showing error! the same format I used
in MVC with `MvcHtmlString` and `HtmlHelper` and it works. Now i'm trying
it in `asp.net core`. Any suggestions rather than "TagHelpers"?

Answer (score 0):

To fix that issue, you need invoke an **instance method** instead of a **static method**:

```
public static IHtmlContent LabelwithStyleFor<TModel, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
  Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
{
    return htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression, new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-form-label" });
}
```